# Save changes made to datatables after closing app (R)

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am making an R app that is keeping track of remaining vacation days of employees. On the first time launching it creates new tables while afterwards all important tables and variables will get stored in reactiveValues. Once I close my app and re-open it I don't want to create the tables from scratch again, I want to use the data that were once stored in my global variables as well. Is this possible?

Comment: If you need persistence, you should store the data in a file local (and writable) to the shiny server or even better in a database. (The local file can be a SQLite database, which is "just a file" but allows SQL access to the underlying data.)

Comment: As it stands, this question is a bit under-detailed. If you aren't able to provide code and a specific problem, then it'll likely be closed. I suggest you look at https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html for some data-persistence recommendations.